# ReferenceError when trying to call functions

Tags: javascript, html, paperjs

I get an uncaught reference error whenever I try to call a javascript function in a separate paperscript tag. I tried a test code

HTML body:

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/paper.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" src="foo1.js" canvas="c"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo2.js"></script>
```

The canvas won't get used in this example, it's just something that paper.js needs to work.

So for the scripts themselves:

foo1.js (paperscript)

```
function blah(){ console.log("blah"); }
```

foo2.js (javascript)

```
window.onload = function{ blah(); }
```

Now, if I load the HTML, the console tells me that blah() throws a reference error. However, if I changed

```
type="text/paperscript"
```

to

```
type="text/javascript"
```

for foo1.js, then the console will display "blah" and no error is thrown. Why is this?

Comment: It might have to do with how browsers runs JavaScript. Normally the browser waits until all scripts are loaded before it runs any code. But since `foo1.js` is `text/paperscript` it gets skipped and `foo2.js` is ran immediately. Ensure the code in `foo2.js` is ran after paper has worked it magic on `foo1.js`

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will only load scripts with type="text/javascript".  The paperscript library could have a loader for scripts with type="text/paperscript" triggered from window.onload.  Try adding an event listener so you don't write over an existing loader.

Example:

```
function myInit() {
 blah();
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', myInit, false); 
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', myInit);
}
```